# how to share photo via facebook android sdk without using an in app login button

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

How do I share a photo to facebook using the android sdk, without putting a facebook login button in my app. ( I want them to go to the facebook app to authorize and come back when they click on the share button rather than logging in first then clicking share in 2 steps).  Specifically I would be doing a facebook open graph post to /me/photos so that it would get uploaded to my default app album.  However I am getting a session error not logged in even when the user clicks through the facebook authentication prompt.

```
final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();


Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state,
            final Exception exception) {
        Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(session, image, new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fact shared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
        });
        request.executeAsync();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you been able to do this? I'm looking for the exact same solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. In order to publish a photo, you need publish permissions, which requires another `requestNewPublishPermissions` call after you first open the session.
2. You're making the request immediately in the `call()` method, without checking if `session.isOpened()`. This is problematic, because:

   a. the session goes through many states (including OPENING, OPENED,
   etc), all of which will result in `call()` being called, and you can
   only make requests when it's in the OPENED or OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED
   state;

   b. there could be exceptions during the opening of a
   session (like if the user cancels), which could cause the session to
   become closed. You need to guard your requests with a
   `session.isOpened()` check.